# GPIO Raspberry Pi LED Loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, led

I am trying to make an LED blink infinitely when I press a button, but when I press a different button for the blinking to stop.  My code makes the button start blinking infinitely, but the second button doesn't stop the LED from blinking.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
#Setting Up All LEDs
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(19,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT)
#Setting Up All Buttons
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
#Button Event Handling
while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(20)
    input_state2 = GPIO.input(21)

        if input_state == False:
        x = 1
        while x == 1:
                GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
                time.sleep(.2)
                GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
                                time.sleep(.2)
                if input_state2 == False:
                    x = 2
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: You only set `input_state2` once, outside the inner loop.  It is therefore impossible for it to ever become False while that loop is running.  You probably shouldn't have either of those `input_state` variables; replace them with the actual `GPIO.input()` call so that the value is always fresh.

Comment: Thanks, if you post that as an answer I can mark it as the correct answer.